# $f_{X}(x)= 1- \frac{ | \frac{x-\alpha}{\beta} | }{\beta}$ distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

I want the distribution function and expectation of a random variable with density:

\begin{align}
f_{X}(x) & =
1 - \frac{\left\vert\,{\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta}}\,\right\vert  }{\beta},\quad   b>0\quad\mbox{and}\quad\alpha \in \mathbb{R}
\\
P(X\leq x) &= \int _{\alpha-\beta} ^{x} 1- \frac{ | \frac{y-\alpha}{\beta} |  }{\beta} dy 
\end{align}
The problem is in the second integration:
$$
\int _{\alpha-\beta} ^{x} \frac{ | \frac{y-\alpha}{\beta} |  }{\beta} dy =  \frac{1}{\beta} \int _{\alpha-\beta} ^{x}| \frac{y-\alpha}{\beta} |dy \ $$    then $u=y-\alpha$

$y \to x \implies u=x-\alpha$

$y \to \alpha - \beta \implies u=-\beta$

$$ = \frac{1}{\beta}\int _{-\beta} ^{x-\alpha}|\frac{u}{\beta}|du$$

And now I don´t know how to integrate that absolute value.

Also I have the same problem with the expectation and variance:

$$E(X)=\int _{\alpha-\beta}^{\alpha+\beta} y \left(1- \frac{ | \frac{y-\alpha}{\beta} |  }{\beta} \right) dy $$

What about this integral?

$$\int _{\alpha-\beta}^{\alpha+\beta}y \left( \frac{ | \frac{y-\alpha}{\beta} |  }{\beta} \right) dy $$

Comment: Is $\beta >0$ not $b > 0$ in second line?

Comment: Sorry $\beta >0$

Answer (score 1):

As $f_X(x)$ is a density function, $f_X(x) \geq 0 $

$\displaystyle \rightarrow 1-\frac{|x-\alpha|}{\beta^2} \geq 0$ ($\because \beta > 0)$

$\displaystyle \rightarrow 1 \geq \frac{|x-\alpha|}{\beta^2}$

$\displaystyle \rightarrow |x-\alpha| \leq \beta^2$

$\displaystyle \rightarrow x \in [\alpha-\beta^2,\, \alpha+\beta^2]$

$\displaystyle
\rightarrow f_X(x) = \begin{cases}
  1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2} & x \in [\alpha-\beta^2,\, \alpha]  \\
  1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta^2}  &  x \in [\alpha,\, \alpha+\beta^2] \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

Thus, we can calculate cdf like below.

$
\displaystyle
\begin{align} 
 F_X(x) & = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f_X(x) \,dx \\ 
        & = \begin{cases}
                \int_{-\infty}^{x}0 \,dx & x < \alpha-\beta^2 \\
                \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha-\beta^2}0 \,dx \, +
                \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{x} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx & x \in [\alpha-\beta^2,\, \alpha]  \\
                \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha-\beta^2}0 \,dx \, +
                \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{\alpha} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx\, +  
                \int_{\alpha}^{x} \, 1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta^2}\, dx
                &  x \in [\alpha,\, \alpha+\beta^2] \\
                \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha-\beta^2}0 \,dx \, +
                \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{\alpha} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx\, +  
                \int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta^2} \, 1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta^2}\, dx \, +
                \int_{\alpha+\beta^2}^{x} \, 0 \, dx
                 & x > \alpha+\beta^2
               \end{cases}     \\ 
           & =   \begin{cases}
  0 & x < \alpha-\beta^2 \\
  \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{x} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx & x \in [\alpha-\beta^2,\, \alpha]  \\
  \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{\alpha} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx\, +  
  \int_{\alpha}^{x} \, 1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta^2}\, dx
  &  x \in [\alpha,\, \alpha+\beta^2] \\
  1 & x > \alpha+\beta^2
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$

You can get expectation and variance of the distribution like this flow.

---

I think the condition is wrong, or my calculation has mistakes because, I get the equation below.
$ \displaystyle
  \int_{\alpha-\beta^2}^{\alpha} \, 1-\frac{\alpha-x}{\beta^2}\, dx\, +  
  \int_{\alpha}^{\alpha+\beta^2} \, 1-\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta^2}\, dx = \beta^2
$

which should be $1$